# regex match based on condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having the following string

```
test test.a test.b test.a.b test2.a test2 test2.a.b
```

and the following regex

```
/(test(\.)(\S*)?)/gi
```

This returns the following `test.a` `test.b` `test.a.b`
What I want is to return `test` as well.

If I make `(\.)?` optional it returns `test2.a` as well and I don't want that.

What I'm looking for is to have a condition. If there is dot after test return `test.whatever.else` else if there is space after `test` return `test` , else do not match anything.

Live example : https://regex101.com/r/ZendrY/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with an optional match of DOT followed by 1 or more non-space character after `test` and wrapped by word boundary on either side:

```
/\btest(?:\.\S+)?\b/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZendrY/5)

Comment: I think this is perfectly good answer, but I'll just point out that the `\b` word boundary will match a few other characters like hyphens, so this will match the `test` in a `test-foo` input. If that's not desired, you could use `(\s|$)` (whitespace or end-of-string) instead of `\b`, but I suppose it's up the OP whether that's actually necessary/desired for whatever input is expected.

Comment: If hyphen or other non-word characters are to be allowed then `/\btest(?:\.\S+)?(?=\s|$)/g` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternation so that `test` is followed by either a dot or a space rather than making the dot optional:

```
/test(?= )|(test(\.)(\S*)?)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding \b for matching the word end as well, e.g.:

`/(test(\.?\b)(\S*)?)/ig`

... or a positive lookahead:

`/(test?(?=[\. ])(\S*))/ig`